# Dynamic pages are not available in nextjs app when i build the app for server upload

Tags: next.js, server, build, out

i made an webpage using nextjs (version 13.4.19) app in which i used dynamic routing.
It is working fine in local but when i build the app it is not creating dynamic pages. I am sharing folder structure for reference.

[image]

here red marked files are of home page and blue marked are index page. I dont get any file for yellow marked file

well maybe this because we cant create dynamic static pages.

so how am i supposed to run this on server...when i run out folder on local also it only shows home page

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using [static exports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports) using the `output` option set to `export`.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  output: 'export',
};
```

SSR and ISR pages require the Next.js server to be running, this is impossible with a static export. Here is a link to see a complete overview of all [unsupported features](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features).

Comment: Yes fabio, i am using static export.
Can you please tell me how should i get the dynamic pages also..I used npm run build. ( that creates .next folder ). when i run it, i get 404 for dynamic pages

Comment: You simply can not achieve what you are looking for. "Dynamic pages" require a non-static export. Read the link I have provided.